# Test services in Mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mockito

I want to test service

```
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExistsUsername() {
        User user = userService.findByUsername("jonki97").get();

    }
}
```

However, during the test he throws me out

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.service.service.UserServiceTest.testExistsUsername(UserServiceTest.java:32)
```

My service still contains repository

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
 }
```

It may be that I missed something wrong and therefore throws null.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any mocks instantiated, even you have this method for initiating mocks. You need a mock of the repository you are calling in your test class:

```
@Mock
UserRepository userRepository;
```

And as well to provide the behavior of the mock (what to do when the method is called). Something like:

```
when(userRepository.findByUsername("jonki97")).thenReturn("OK");
// test the method after
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing https://zapodaj.net/33a4d1abeab84.png.html

Comment: Inject the Mocks into the class you want to test with @InjectMocks. Also, use a @RunWIth(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) (or SpringRunner) annotation on the test class

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Runner

**@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)**

This works for me:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Before 
    public void setup(){

        when(userRepository.findByUsername("jonki97")).thenReturn("jonki97");
    }

        @Test
        public void testExistsUsername() {
            String user = userRepository.findByUsername("jonki97");
            assertEquals("jonki97", user);

        }

}
```